# Trying to navigate through an API, can't get past the first layer

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm new at this, and the last couple questions I asked didn't seem to have enough detail so I'm going to try this one with as much details as I can think of.

I'm trying to practice navigating through APIs so that I can build an app using underscore.js. I have my code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
 });
```

Now that works. I can see the data in my console, but if I try to go deeper into the data.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data.title);
    }
});
```

The console says undefined. I've looked all over for how to fix this, but nothing is working. I'm sure it's something simple I'm missing, but I have no idea what it is.

Comment: `data` is an `array` so you must either loop through the collection or target a specific `index` from that array before you can target a property like `title` **=>** `data[?].property` **[x]** being the `index` and **.property** the `property` you wish to access.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, your data is an array, it's not a json object. That's why you got undefined when trying to access title
Try this:

```
for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
   console.log(data[i].title);
}
```

> Please open the snippet below to see a working example.

```js
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
  type: 'GET',
  success: function(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      console.log(data[i].title);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```